# Failed to successfully launch or connect to a child MSBuild.exe process. Verify that the MSBuild.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

First time this happens to me.

Ran the build and got this error.

When I rebuild other `sln` all works fine.

> Error 1   The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
>   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.BuildAbortedException: Build was canceled.
>   Failed to successfully launch or connect to a child MSBuild.exe
>   process. Verify that the MSBuild.exe
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" launches
>   successfully, and that it is loading the same microsoft.build.dll that
>   the launching process loaded. If the location seems incorrect, try
>   specifying the correct location in the BuildParameters object, or with
>   the MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable.    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId,
>   INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider
>   nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration
>   configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1
>   responses)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node,
>   BuildRequestBlocker blocker)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission
>   submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker
>   blocker)  D:\MaM\Server\ClientServices\Dev\ClientService
>   1.4\Conduit.Mam.ClientServices.Common.Initizliaer\Conduit.Mam.ClientServices.Common.Initizliaer.csproj    Conduit.Mam.ClientServices.Common.Initizliaer

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Quitting and re-opening Visual Studio solved it for me.

Comment: When I quit visual studio and try to relaunch it immediately says 'out of memory' until I log off and log back in.

Comment: i have same issue and when i do this solution i get same issue  that doug had. Doug any way to resolve this?

Comment: I also get "out of memory" message.  I have 16GB memory and task manager says 60% free - so it should be enough to start visual studio. Quitting and re-opening visual Studio is not really a "solution".  Restarting the computer "fixes" it temporarily, but it happens again eventually.  Rebooting all the time is not a real solution either.

Comment: Epic amount of upvotes for such a simple answer, but +1 because it worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue this morning. This error usually appears when your system is running low on memory. If quitting and re-opening VS doesn't do the trick, try closing some of the other applications that are currently running. If all else fails try restarting your system.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraswadehra/archive/2014/01/04/the-build-stopped-unexpectedly-because-of-an-internal-failure.aspx

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the topic.  But I have 16GB memory and over 60% free according to task manager.  After the MsBuild fail message I cannot restart Visual Studio due to "out of memory" error.  There is no way I am actually out of memory. Restarting the system fixes it, but this is very annoying, as a developer I need to build a lot and restarting the machine is a big interruption from the flow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried everything in this post (restart, reboot, etc.) and nothing helps. Try Running VS2012 as Administrator and see if that helps.