# Sometimes when i make BUILD > Rebuild Solution i'm getting error: he build stopped unexpectedly because of a an internal failure why?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace CheatEngineMemoryScan
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        List<string> Processes = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                string t = string.Format("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
                Processes.Add(t);
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Before this i had some more code i deleted it i didn't have any errors.
But once i did BUILD > Rebuild Solution i'm getting an error:

```
Error   1   The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.BuildAbortedException: Build was canceled. Failed to successfully launch or connect to a child MSBuild.exe process. Verify that the MSBuild.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" launches successfully, and that it is loading the same microsoft.build.dll that the launching process loaded. If the location seems incorrect, try specifying the correct location in the BuildParameters object, or with the MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable.
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker) D:\C-Sharp\Scan\Scan\Scan\Scan.csproj   Scan
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Failed to successfully launch or connect to a child MSBuild.exe process. Verify that the MSBuild.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561278/failed-to-successfully-launch-or-connect-to-a-child-msbuild-exe-process-verify). Restart Visual Studio. If that doesn't resolve the issue, update your question showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shown code is pretty much ok.There are no any issues with compiling.you just need to restart Visual studio. It will resolve your problem.

Typically when you encounter an issue like this, I would resort to the following troubleshooting steps :

1. Attempt to Rebuild your Project / Solution
2. Attempt to "Clean" your Project / Solution
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Running Visual Studio as an Administrator

For more information about this issue, please refer to the following [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2298853)